# How to print 2D array as single 1D row?

Tags: fortran

I am constructing a very simple 2D array in fortran with the following loop:

```
      do i = 1, N
         do j = 1, M
            A(i, j) = i * 10 + j
         end do
      end do
```

I then created a subroutine to print this as a 2D array:

```
      implicit none

      real*8 A(N, M)
      integer i, j

      do i = 1, N
         do j = 1, M
            write(*, ' (F4.0)', advance='no') A(i, j) ! this is Fortran90
         end do
         write(*, *)
      end do

      end subroutine
```

And the output is:

```
 print_matrix
 11. 12. 13. 14.
 21. 22. 23. 24.
 31. 32. 33. 34.
```

I now want to take all of the elements and put them into a single row in the sequential order of the rows themselves. (I hope that made sense). And I want to make a print function that does this without changing the main function.

I'm very close to what I want with the following subroutine:

```
      implicit none

      real*8 A(N, M)
      integer i

      do i = 1, N
          write(*, ' (F4.0)', advance='no') A(i,:) ! this is Fortran90
      write(*, *)
      end do

      end subroutine
```

The output of this is

```
 print_matrix_linear
 11.
 12.
 13.
 14.
 21.
 22.
 23.
 24.
 31.
 32.
 33.
 34.
```

But this is not quite what I want. The order of the elements is correct, but this is all one *column*. I basically want to transpose this array and put it all into one *row*.

Please provide some suggestions for how I might do this. Thank you so much!

-CJW

Comment: do not use `real*8`, it is non-standard and non-portable and potentially problematic. See, for example, the discussion at the end of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845843/plain-vs-allocatable-pointer-arrays-fortran-advice/54846666#54846666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial solution was not too far off:

```
write(*, '(F4.0)', advance='no') A(i, :)
```

With `advance='no'`, the write statement would not advance the line at the end, except that you only give the format for a single value, but pass 4 values into it.

If you write more values than the format statement expects, it will write them out in multiple lines, and only the final value will have the `advance='no'` honoured, so you'd get something like:

```
11.
12.
13.
14. 21.
22.
23.
24. 31.
...
```

It's just that you added a new

```
write(*, *)
```

in the next line which then advances the line and makes it all a single column in the output.

You can, in your format, add the number of elements. You might want to use something like this: `'(4F4.0)'`. -- Or, if you don't know how many values are there, you can use an asterisk: `'(*(F4.0))'`. (Unfortunately, the second set of parentheses is necessary with the asterisk.)

By changing this format, and removing the empty `write` statement, you should get what you want.

Now if I may be so bold, a few things about the format.

- You have an initial space, like this: `' (F4.0)'` -- this space doesn't do anything. The format will mean that exactly 4 characters (including the period) are reserved per value. If you want to add a space into each value, you have to do it this way: `'(X,F4.0)'` or `'(" ",F4.0)'`.

  Or, if you're lazy, just give it one more character to write the value: `(F5.0)`
- Since multi-dimensional arrays in fortran change indices quickest the way you want to print them anyway, you can replace your whole print loop with just:

  ```
  write(*, '(*(X, F4.0))') A
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer! I simply put the `write(*, *)` line outside of the do statement to get the command line in the terminal on to the next line. I then changed to `' (*(F4.0))'` and this now prints exactly what I want! And you were right, the extra space before `(F4.0)` was unnecessary. Thank you so much for this insight :)